# How to login as admin user programatically in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I want to login as admin user programatically in Drupal 7. If forgot password or need a quick login as any user.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with

Answer (score 0):

If you can execute code or change the code in a file, you can set the global $user like this:

```
$GLOBALS['user'] = user_load(1);
```

Be VERY careful doing this to all anonymous users... You can do it with a GET parameter, inside a code that you know that will be executed.

```
<?php
function mymodule_init() {
  if ($_GET['key']=='SOME-DIFFICULT-RANDOM-STRING') {
    $GLOBALS['user'] = user_load(1);
  }
}
```

After that, remember to delete those lines.

You can also bootstrap Drupal and do the same thing programmatically. Override global $user with the loaded user you want to become.

Hope that helps.